Create a curved timeline in Tex
I am trying to create a timeline that includes 24 time points placed in a curved arrow as follows:

I have a version of a straight arrow (From @Gonzalo Medina), but it is longer than the page width, so I want to have a curved timeline as above. I would like to ask for your help. Thank you so much.
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows,fit,calc}

\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{50,130,230}
\definecolor{circlecolor}{RGB}{79,129,189}
\colorlet{textcolor}{white}
\colorlet{bordercolor}{white}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcounter{task}

\newlength\taskwidth
\newlength\taskvsep

\setlength\taskwidth{2.5cm}
\setlength\taskvsep{17pt}

\def\taskpos{}
\def\taskanchor{}

\newcommand\task[1]{%
  {\parbox[t]{\taskwidth}{\scriptsize\Centering#1}}}

\tikzset{
inner/.style={
  on chain,
  circle,
  inner sep=1pt,
  fill=circlecolor,
  line width=0.5pt,
  draw=bordercolor,
},
on grid
}

\newcommand\Time[2][]{%
\node[inner xsep=0pt] (c1) {\phantom{A}};
\stepcounter{task}
\ifodd\thetask\relax
  \renewcommand\taskpos{\taskvsep}\renewcommand\taskanchor{south}
\else
  \renewcommand\taskpos{-\taskvsep}\renewcommand\taskanchor{north}
\fi
\node[inner,font=\footnotesize\sffamily\color{textcolor}]    
  (c\the\numexpr\value{task}+1\relax) {#1};
\node[anchor=\taskanchor,yshift=\taskpos] 
  at (c\the\numexpr\value{task}+1\relax) {\task{#2}};
}

\newcommand\drawarrow{a
\ifnum\thetask=0\relax
  \node[on chain] (c1) {};
\fi
\node[on chain] (f) {};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[
  inner sep=10pt,
  single arrow,
  single arrow head extend=0.5cm,
  draw=none,
  fill=arrowcolor,
  fit= (c1) (f)
] (arrow) {};
\fill[white] 
  (arrow.before tail) -- (c1|-arrow.east) -- (arrow.after tail) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newenvironment{timeline}[1][node distance=.5\taskwidth]
  {\par\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,#1]}
  {\drawarrow\end{tikzpicture}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{timeline}
\Time[1958]{Task 1}
\Time[1959]{Task 2}
\Time[1960]{Task 3}
\Time[1961]{Task 4}
\Time[1962]{Task 5}
\Time[1963]{Task 6}
\Time[1964]{Task 7}
\Time[1965]{Task 8}
\Time[1966]{Task 9}
\Time[1967]{Task 10}
\Time[1968]{Task 11}
\Time[1969]{Task 12}
\Time[1970]{Task 13}
\Time[1971]{Task 14}
\Time[1972]{Task 15}
\Time[1973]{Task 16}
\Time[1974]{Task 17}
\Time[1975]{Task 18}
\Time[1976]{Task 19}
\Time[1977]{Task 20}
\Time[1978]{Task 21}
\Time[1979]{Task 22}
\Time[1980]{Task 23}
\Time[1981]{Task 24}
\end{timeline}

\end{document}

Ref.: How can I make a standard timeline? [added by community]

@GonzaloMedina, can you help me please?

You can only ping people who are involved with the question e.g. who've written a comment or (I think) edited.

@cfr Yes, I think so. I have pinged him in another post. Thank you.

To get started...

For an arrow on several lines, I suggest using the arrows.meta library
 % p.221
 %\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
 \tikz \draw [line width=1ex,
 {Triangle Cap[reversed]-{Latex[length=0pt +2]}}]
 (0,0) -- (1,0);


For the label task1, task2... I use \node also with label distance in \tikzset


EDIT : With a more rounded shape, I use a circle (with a clip) and I add 2 arguments in bar arrow #1 for the start
#2 for the finish.

I add a length \arrowvsep for the distance between the arrows

The code
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/715875/create-a-curved-timeline-in-tex
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}
%  color
\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{50,130,230}
\definecolor{circlecolor}{RGB}{79,129,189}
\colorlet{textcolor}{white}
\colorlet{bordercolor}{white}
%  length
\newlength\taskwidth
\newlength\taskvsep
\newlength\arrowvsep%<-- added
\setlength\taskwidth{2.cm}
\setlength\taskvsep{1.5ex}
\setlength\arrowvsep{3.cm}
%
\begin{document}
%in th doc p.601
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm]
    % The chain is called just "chain"
    \draw[help lines] (0,-1) grid (2,1);
    \node [on chain] {A};
    \node [on chain] {B};
    \node [on chain] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm]
    % The chain is called just "chain"
    \draw[help lines] (0,-1) grid (2,1);
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {A};
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {B};
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
%\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=1cm,on grid]
    % The chain is called just "chain"
    \draw[help lines] (0,-1) grid (2,1);
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {A};
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {B};
    \node [on chain,circle,draw] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going right,
    start chain=2 going left,
    node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style=draw]
    \draw[help lines] (0,-2) grid (3,1);
    \node [on chain=1] {A};
    \node [on chain=1] {B};
    \node [on chain=1] (C){C};
    \node [on chain=2] at ([shift={(0.5cm,-1cm)}]C) {0};
    \node [on chain=2] {1};
    \node [on chain=2] {2};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
        % p.221
        %\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
        \tikz \draw [line width=1cm,
        {Triangle Cap[reversed]-{Latex[length=0pt +2]}}]
        (0,0) -- (5,0);


 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=1cm,
        {Triangle Cap[reversed]-}]
        (0,0) -- (5,0);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (5,-3) rectangle (6.5,1.5);
            \draw[line width=1cm] (5,-1) circle[radius=1cm]; 
        \end{scope}
    \draw [line width=1cm,
        -{Latex[length=0pt +2]}]
        (5,-2) -- (0,-2);
 \end{tikzpicture}


\tikzset{
    node distance=1.5cm,
    on grid,
    bar height/.initial=1.2cm,
    bar arrow/.style args={#1/#2}%
        {%
            #1-#2,
            arrowcolor,
            line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar height},
            %rounded corners=5mm
        },
    inner/.style=
        {
            %on chain,
            circle,
            inner sep=1pt,
            minimum width=1cm,
            fill=circlecolor,
            line width=0.5pt,
            draw=bordercolor,
            font=\footnotesize\sffamily\color{textcolor},
        },
    label distance=\taskvsep
}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent\centering
\fbox{%<--- comment on the final document
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [%
        trim left=-1.5cm,% begin of the arrow at -1.5
        start chain=1 going right,
        start chain=2 going left,
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (15,-4);%<-- comment in the final doc
    % \draw[bar arrow] (-1.5,0) -- (15,0) -- ++(0,-\arrowvsep)--(-1.5,-\arrowvsep);
    \draw[bar arrow={Triangle Cap[reversed]/{}}] (-1.5,0) -- (14,0);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (14,-3.7) rectangle (16.2,1.5);
        \draw[bar arrow={{}/{}}] (14,-0.5\arrowvsep) circle[radius=0.5\arrowvsep]; 
    \end{scope}
    \draw[bar arrow={{}/{{Latex[arrowcolor, length=0pt +2]}}}] (14,-\arrowvsep) -- (-0.5\arrowvsep,-\arrowvsep);
    
    \foreach \i/\d in{
        1/1958,
        2/1958,
        3/1960,
        4/1961,
        5/1962,
        6/1963,
        7/1964,
        8/1965,
        9/1966,
        10/1967}
        {
            \node[inner,on chain=1] (N_\i)  {\d};
            \node also [label=\ifodd\i above\else below\fi:task\i] (N_\i);
        }
    \node [on chain=2] at ([shift={(1cm,-\arrowvsep)}]N_10) {};
    \foreach \i in{11,...,19}
        {
            \node[inner,on chain=2] (N_\i) {Date\i};
            \node also [label=\ifodd\i below\else above\fi:task\i] (N_\i);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}



You save my day. Thank you so much @pascal974.

I liked this type of graphic and saw that it lent itself to the solutions I have for printing massive labels, the path is drawn in parts starting from the tail towards the head, when the number of sections in a row reaches a specific value , the respective curve is drawn and the sections are drawn in the opposite direction, after it completes double the value of the number of sections, the other curve is drawn and the counter is reset, thus making the path grow automatically, finally stopping the head it was necessary to condition the drawings to the input of text data, which instead of drawing the body draws the head when the text is end and in that case there are 2 options if it is going or returning, if it is returning You must place reverse, so that it draws the head in the opposite direction, I learned a lot by making this, taking things from here and there, that's why I share it and because of the weekend at home.
I do this type of code organization because the data can be ordered in rows, and in the case of generating labels I can obtain them quickly using a data sheet such as Excel, for example, exporting their respective tikz code format in a final box.
I had some of the texts completed with a chatbot with certain topics, I hope they are not uncomfortable.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{helvet}
\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{50,130,230}

\begin{document}
    \def\NTsize{\sf\bfseries\normalsize}
    \def\CTsize{\sf\bfseries\normalsize}
    
    \def\BODY#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=0,transform shape]
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{end}}{%Draw The end Arrow Head
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{reverse}}{
                    \filldraw[#6]%Reversed Arrow
                        (-1pt,#5*0.5+#7/2)
                            -- ++(#4*0.5+1pt,0)
                            -- ++ (0,3mm) 
                            -- (#4,#5*0.5)
                            -- (#4*0.5,#5*0.5-#7/2-3mm)
                            -- ++(0,3mm)
                            -- ++(-#4*0.5-1pt,0);
                    }{
                    \filldraw[#6]%Normal Arrow
                        (#4+1pt,#5*0.5+#7/2)
                            -- ++(-#4*0.5-1pt,0)
                            -- ++ (0,3mm)
                            -- (0,#5*0.5)
                            -- (#4*0.5,#5*0.5-#7/2-3mm)
                            -- ++(0,3mm)
                            -- ++(#4*0.5+1pt,0);
                }
            }{% Draw the normal body
                \filldraw[#6] (0,#5*0.5+#7/2) rectangle ++(#4,-#7);
                \draw[white](#4*0.5,#5*0.5) node[circle,draw,fill=#6!70!black, minimum size=#7-3mm,font=\NTsize](temp){#2};
                \draw(temp)+(#8:#9) node[text width=#4-3mm, align=center,font=\CTsize](t2){#3};
                \draw[#6!40!white, preaction={draw,#6, line width=2pt}](temp)--(t2);
            }               
        \end{scope} 
    }

    \def\TAIL#1#2#3#4#5{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
            \filldraw[#4] (#2+1pt,#3*0.5+#5/2)-- ++(-#2*0.5-1pt,0) -- (#2*0.75,#3*0.5) -- (#2*0.5,#3*0.5-#5/2) -- ++ (1pt+#2*0.5,0);
        \end{scope} 
    }
    
    \def\CURVE#1#2#3#4#5#6{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},#4,transform shape]
            \filldraw[#5](-1pt,#3*0.5-#6/2) -- ++(1pt,0) arc (90:-90:#3*0.5-#6/2) -- ++(-1pt,0)-- ++(0,-#6) -- ++(1pt,0) arc (-90:90:#3/2+#6/2)--++(-1pt,0);
        \end{scope} 
    }
    
    \def\SNAKETEXT#1(#2)[#3][#4][#5]#6#7{%\SNAKETEXT{Contents}(Position)[x_dim][y_dim][colour]{tasks_per_line}{arrow size}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
            \edef\Shiftx{0}
            \edef\Shifty{0}
            \pgfmathparse{int(#6*2)}
            \xdef\tpl{\pgfmathresult}
            \foreach \cod/\direc/\dist/\desc [count=\ctr from 0] in {#1}{
                \ifnum\ctr=0
                    \TAIL{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}
                \fi
                \ifnum\ctr<#6
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx+1)}
                    \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult}
                    \BODY{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{\cod}{\desc}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}{\direc}{\dist}
                \fi
                \ifnum\ctr=#6
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx+1)}
                    \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult}
                    \CURVE{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{#3}{#4}{}{#5}{#7}
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx-1)}
                    \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult}
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shifty+1)}
                    \xdef\Shifty{\pgfmathresult}
                    \BODY{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{\cod}{\desc}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}{\direc}{\dist}
                \fi
                \ifnum\ctr>#6
                    \ifnum\ctr<\tpl
                        \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx-1)}
                        \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult} 
                        \BODY{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{\cod}{\desc}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}{\direc}{\dist}
                    \fi
                \fi
                \ifnum\ctr=\tpl
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx-1)}
                    \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult}
                    \CURVE{\Shiftx*#3+#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{#3}{#4}{xscale=-1}{#5}{#7}
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shifty+1)}
                    \xdef\Shifty{\pgfmathresult}
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Shiftx+1)}
                    \xdef\Shiftx{\pgfmathresult}
                    \BODY{\Shiftx*#3,-\Shifty*#4-#4}{\cod}{\desc}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}{\direc}{\dist}
                    \xdef\ctr{0}
                \fi
            }
        \end{scope} 
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \SNAKETEXT{
            task1/90/20mm/Detail of task 1,
            task2/-90/20mm/Detail of task 2,
            task3/90/20mm/Detail of task 3,
            task4/-90/20mm/Detail of task 4,
            task5/90/23mm/Some manual text input for more details,
            task6/-90/23mm/Become a Professional Procrastinator,
            task7/90/20mm/Organize Your Clutter,
            task8/-90/20mm/Master the Art of Napping,
            task9/90/20mm/Attend a Productivity Seminar,
            task10/-90/23mm/Create a To-Do List for Doing Nothing,
            task11/-90/20mm/Practice Active Inactivity,
            task12/90/20mm/Become an Expert at Waiting,
            task13/-90/20mm/Write a Book on Doing Nothing,
            task14/90/20mm/Achieving Zen in Pajamas,
            task15/-90/20mm/Watch 10 Hours of Cat Videos,
            task16/90/23mm/Reorganized My Sock Drawer Instead of Studying,
            task17/-90/30mm/Dedicate hours each day to scrolling through social media feeds.,
            task18/90/25mm/Spend hours contemplating the meaning of life,
            task19/-90/20mm/Some task like doing nothing,
            end/end/end/end%
        }(0,0)[25mm][50mm][arrowcolor]{10}{20mm}
    
        %Changing the font sizes
        \def\NTsize{\sf\bfseries\scriptsize}
        \def\CTsize{\sf\bfseries\scriptsize}
        \SNAKETEXT{
            JAN-30/-90/15mm/Polar Bear Plunge Day,
            FEB-29/90/15mm/International Lost Sock Memorial Day,
            MAR-13/-90/15mm/Global Labyrinth Day,
            APR-30/90/15mm/National Awkward Silence Appreciation Day,
            MAY-15/-90/15mm/World Emoji Day,
            JUN-07/-90/15mm/National Talk Like a Pirate Day,
            JUL-15/90/15mm/Global Prohibition Day,
            AUG-12/-90/15mm/National Overthinking Awareness Weeky,
            SEP-06/90/15mm/World Couch Potato Championship,
            OCT-17/-90/15mm/National Socks-with-Sandals Day,
            NOV-28/-90/15mm/ Global Pajama Conference,
            DEC-25/90/15mm/World Simultaneous Eye Roll Day ,
            end/end/end/reverse%
        }(0,-13)[25mm][30mm][green!50!black]{5}{15mm}
    
        %Changing the font sizes
        \def\NTsize{\sf\bfseries\tiny}
        \def\CTsize{\sf\bfseries\tiny}
        \SNAKETEXT{
            A/90/5mm/cmt-stg1,
            B/90/5mm/cmt-stg2,
            C/90/5mm/cmt-stg3
            D/90/5mm/cmt-stg4,
            E/90/5mm/cmt-stg5,
            F/90/5mm/cmt-stg6,
            G/90/5mm/cmt-stg7,
            H/90/5mm/cmt-stg8,
            I/90/5mm/cmt-stg9,
            J/90/5mm/cmt-stg10,
            K/90/5mm/cmt-stg11,
            L/90/5mm/cmt-stg12,
            M/90/5mm/cmt-stg13,
            N/90/5mm/cmt-stg14,
            M/90/5mm/cmt-stg15,
            O/90/5mm/cmt-stg16,
            end/end/end/end%
        }(18,-11)[20mm][10mm][cyan!50!green]{2}{5mm}
    
        %Changing the font sizes
        \def\NTsize{\sf\bfseries\tiny}
        \def\CTsize{\sf\bfseries\tiny}
        \SNAKETEXT{
            A/90/5mm/cmt-stg1,
            B/90/5mm/cmt-stg2,
            C/90/5mm/cmt-stg3
            D/90/5mm/cmt-stg4,
            E/90/5mm/cmt-stg5,
            F/90/5mm/cmt-stg6,
            G/90/5mm/cmt-stg7,
            H/90/5mm/cmt-stg8,
            I/90/5mm/cmt-stg9,
            J/90/5mm/cmt-stg10,
            K/90/5mm/cmt-stg11,
            L/90/5mm/cmt-stg12,
            M/90/5mm/cmt-stg13,
            N/90/5mm/cmt-stg14,
            M/90/5mm/cmt-stg15,
            O/90/5mm/cmt-stg16,
            P/90/5mm/cmt-stg17,
            Q/90/5mm/cmt-stg18,
            end/end/end/reverse%
        }(24,-11)[20mm][10mm][red!50!blue]{2}{5mm}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


So great! Thank you so much @J Leon V.
